# How to replace some lines after second occurrence of a string in Unix Shell scripting

Tags: unix, replace

### Input Text file:

```
COMMENT 'Sample Table'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'xxxxxxx'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'xxxx'
```

**Output Needed :**

```
COMMENT 'Sample Table'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'xxxxxxx'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION
  'xxxx'
```

After the second occuracne of 'STORED AS' next word should be ORC and next three lines should be removed. What command can be used in Unix ?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this problem? You need to post your efforts made to attract more answers

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. If the input is saved in a file sample.txt 
the following command gave the expected output.

awk '/STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/{c++;if(c==2){sub("STORED AS INPUTFORMAT","STORED AS ORC\nzzzz");c=0}}1' sample.txt | sed -e '/zzzz/,+3d'